# Delete only first appearance of element into list?

Tags: elisp

How to delete only first appearance of element into list (elisp) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this elisp (which requires `cl`):

```
(defun remove-first (elt seq)
  (let ((remove-first t))
    (remove-if (lambda (e) (when (and remove-first (equal elt e))
                             (setq remove-first nil)
                             t))
               seq)))
```

Note: this makes a copy of the original list.  For one using side-effects, try this:

```
(defun remove-first* (elt seq)
  (if (equal elt (car seq))
      (cdr seq)
    (while (cdr seq)
      (if (equal elt (cadr seq))
          (progn (setcdr seq (cddr seq))
                 (setq seq nil))
        (setq seq (cdr seq))))
    seq))
```

Note: when the first element is the one removed, just the `cdr` is returned, so as always with this type of operation, invoke it like so:

```
(setq mylist (remove-first* 3 mylist))
```

Answer (score 9):

The Common Lisp [sequence-editing functions](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html) (`remove` and friends) take a `:count` keyword argument:

> *Count*, if supplied, limits the number of elements removed or deleted; if more than *count* elements satisfy the test, then of these elements only the leftmost or rightmost, depending on *from-end*, are deleted or removed, as many as specified by *count*. If *count* is supplied and negative, the behavior is as if zero had been supplied instead. If *count* is `nil`, all matching items are affected.

For example:

```
ELISP> (require 'cl)
cl

ELISP> (remove* 1 '(1 2 1 3 1 4) :count 1)
(2 1 3 1 4)

ELISP> (remove* 1 '(1 2 1 3 1 4) :count 2)
(2 3 1 4)

ELISP> (remove* 1 '(1 2 1 3 1 4) :count 2 :from-end t)
(1 2 3 4)
```

(Note that Emacs already had its own function called `remove`, so the `cl` package has to use the name `remove*`.)

Comment: Starting with Emacs 24.3 you can use CL functions by prefixing `cl-`, so you can use `cl-remove`.

Answer (score 2):

The noob's code for elisp. `position` can be found into `cl-seq.el`.

```
(defun remove-first (elem lst)
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (position elem lst) nil ) (progn (setq lst lst) )
  (progn
  (setq out1 (nthcdr (+ 1 (position elem lst)) lst))
  (setq out2 (nbutlast lst (- (length lst) (position elem lst) ) ) )
  (delq nil (append out2 out1))
  ))
)
```

To remove 3 from mylist, will be called as

```
>(setq mylist '(1 2 3 4 3 3))
>(setq mylist (remove-first 3 mylist))
(1 2 4 3 3)
```